# jenkins build fail on another Mac due to provisioning profile not found

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am trying to build project on another mac,not the one on which I'm developing.And I chose Jenkins to help with it.
I have seen similar questions,but my situation seems different.

Below is the log from Jenkins console:

[image]

something has been done before:

1. export the profile from organizer of the old one and import to the new one.
2. copy the keys from keychain and copy to the new Mac's keychain,including system.
3. specify the name of provisioning profile in the project.

I'm not sure if anyone has seen the same thing,but if anyone does,please kindly show me some tips to overcome this,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you included are for copying/replacing certificates and identities. Provisioning profiles are different.

The provisioning profiles are located under `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. Please note these have to be available for the user under which Jenkins is running.

Locate the provisioning profile on your old machine, and copy it to the new. The provisioning profile has a filename `<UUID>.mobileprovision`. The UUID is the number you see in your error message

Alternatively, launching Xcode on the new machine, and letting it sync with all latest profiles would work too, as long as your run it with Jenkins' user.